# Django check when user created

Tags: python, django

So in any Django project, it is fairly simple to tell if an object has been created by overriding the `save` method:

```
def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    created = False
    if not self.pk:
        created = True
    super(ModelName, self).save(*args,**kwargs)
    if created:
        #do what you want or call a signal
```

But I need to call a function after a `User` is created from [django.contrib.auth.models.User](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/auth/#django.contrib.auth.models.User). I would prefer not to have to actually edit the user model's `save` method.

**How could I go about doing this?**

## Note:

using `pre_save` will not work because none of the info from the model will be available, and that is necessary.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [post_save](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/signals/#post-save) signal.

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.db.models.signals import post_save
from django.dispatch import receiver

@receiver(post_save)
def do_your_thing(sender, **kwargs):
    if sender is User:
        if kwargs["created"]:
            print kwargs["instance"].password
            # do your thing
```

Comment: I'd say post_save, given that the OP "need to call a function after a User is created"

Comment: WOW, I can't believe I missed that! and @astreal, post save would not work because after the first save, there is a primary key, so it would be impossible to tell if it was created or just a save, but before the first save there is no self.pk.

Comment: I will accept this as soon as I am allowed. I still cannot believe I missed this ahha, so simple

Comment: I just realized that this will not work. I have described why in my question. Please take alook

Comment: I would expand the example to check the value of self.created_on.

Comment: @Ryan, I've edited my answer to use post_save. You can use `kwargs["created"]` to determine if a new instance was created. @astreal was right.

Comment: @NigelTufnel I just want to clarify...is `kwargs["created"]` because of my `created` variable, or is that always the case and a kwarg that Django supplies...because I cannot edit the actual User model so although this answers my question, it may not actually solve my problem

Comment: @Ryan, I'm not sure I've understood the `created` bit. If you want to edit User model then the `pre_save` signal is the way to go (`post_save` is fired after the instance is saved in a database). Can you post the code that shows that `pre_save` won't work here (I've just tried `pre_save` and it did fine)? Probably it's better to create another question.